# C++ unit test framework again

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing

I have been looking for specific properties from a unit test framework in c++ but I have struggled find all of the following properties in a framework:

1. Creation of Stubs (only in c++test).
2. Has Code-Coverage tool (only in c++test).
3. VS integration (Common enough)
4. Fixtures (very common in most c++ frame works)
5. Integration with a continuous build system (unable to find it at all in any Framework)
6. Predicate support (Very rare, only able to find that boost has this)

Anyone know of any frameworks which have all these properties (or most of them)?

Comment: why does #5 have to be a part of your unit test lib? Seems like that'd be the the job of a separate component.

Comment: I'm not sure why #2 and #5 are part of the unit testing framework. I've never seen a unit testing framework with code coverage personally (or at least never used one). You could try any of the ones listed here: http://open-tube.com/10-code-coverage-tools-c-c

Comment: Don't know what you mean by predicate support. Google test has ASSERT_THAT and friends...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. [GoogleMock](http://code.google.com/p/googlemock/) from Google or [Isolator++](http://www.typemock.com/isolatorpp-product-page) from Typemock. Isolator++ is a mocking framework which works with several UT frameworks.
2. You don't need that as part of a UT framework (you can instrument binaries and get coverage in VS).
3. Isolator++ has VS integration AFAIK.
4. Like you are saying this is very common, so it will be hard to not find it in mainstream frameworks.
5. The continuous build system should support your framework if you really want that (TeamCity supports a couple of them for example). Otherwise you can always wrap it with some scripts.
6. Not sure what you require here.

HTH.